# ¿Cómo remover espacios blancos de caroufredsel cuando se mueve?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy usando este plugin Caroufredsel pero me deja un espacio en blanco a la derecha cada vez que hace un "slide", y me gustaría que una imagen vaya enseguida después de la otra.

Éste es mi codigo html, css y js:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict"

  $('#slider-carousel').caroufredsel({
    responsive: true,
    width: '100%',
    circular: true,
    align: 'center',

    scroll: {
      items: 1,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      duration: 1000,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      timeoutDuration: 3000,
      onBefore: function() {
        $('ul#slider-carousel li')
          .animate({
            opacity: 0.5
          }, 250);
      },
      onAfter: function() {
        $('ul#slider-carousel li')
          .filter(':eq(1)')
          .animate({
            opacity: 1
          }, 250);
      }
    },

    auto: true,

    items: {
      visible: {
        min: 1,
        max: 1,

      },
      start: -1,

      height: "variable"
    },
    pagination: {
      container: ".sliderpager",
      anchorBuilder: false
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/*slider*/

.container {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .body-content {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider ul.slider-carousel {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.caroufredsel_wraper {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider,
.slider ul.slider-carousel,
.slider ul.slider-carousel li {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.slider ul.slider-carousel li h3 {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.slider ul.slider-carousel li p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.img1 {
  background: url('https://placehold.it/500x300/ff0000');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.img2 {
  background: url('https://placehold.it/500x300/00ff00');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.img3 {
  background: url('https://placehold.it/500x300/0000ff');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.slider ul.sliderpager li.selected a {
  color: #E74C3C;
}

.slider ul.sliderpager li a {
  color: #34495E;
}

.slider ul.sliderpager li {
  padding: 0 3px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.caroufredsel/6.2.1/jquery.carouFredSel.packed.js"></script>

<!-- slider -->
<div class="slider" id="slider">
  <ul class="slider-carousel" id="slider-carousel">
    <li class="img1">
      <h3></h3>
      <p></p>
    </li>
    <li class="img2">
      <h3></h3>
      <p></p>
    </li>
    <li class="img3">
      <h3></h3>
      <p></p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sliderpager">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que los elementos del carrusel son `li`  que se muestran como bloque y por eso no permiten un elemento en paralelo con ellos. Una posible solución sería hacer que los `li` floten. Para ello, lo único que tienes que añadir a tu CSS es esto:

```
.slider, .slider ul.slider-carousel, .slider ul.slider-carousel li {
   float: left;
}
```

Y ya no verás el espacio en blanco entre slides. Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict"

  $('#slider-carousel').caroufredsel({
    responsive: true,
    width: '100%',
    circular: true,
    align: 'center',

    scroll: {
      items: 1,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      duration: 1000,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      timeoutDuration: 3000,
      onBefore: function() {
        $('ul#slider-carousel li')
          .animate({
            opacity: 0.5
          }, 250);
      },
      onAfter: function() {
        $('ul#slider-carousel li')
          .filter(':eq(1)')
          .animate({
            opacity: 1
          }, 250);
      }
    },

    auto: true,

    items: {
      visible: {
        min: 1,
        max: 1,

      },
      start: -1,

      height: "variable"
    },
    pagination: {
      container: ".sliderpager",
      anchorBuilder: false
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.slider, .slider ul.slider-carousel, .slider ul.slider-carousel li {
   float: left;
}

/*slider*/

.container {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .body-content {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider ul.slider-carousel {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.caroufredsel_wraper {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider,
.slider ul.slider-carousel,
.slider ul.slider-carousel li {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.slider ul.slider-carousel li h3 {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.slider ul.slider-carousel li p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.img1 {
  background: url('https://placehold.it/500x300/ff0000');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.img2 {
  background: url('https://placehold.it/500x300/00ff00');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.img3 {
  background: url('https://placehold.it/500x300/0000ff');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.slider ul.sliderpager li.selected a {
  color: #E74C3C;
}

.slider ul.sliderpager li a {
  color: #34495E;
}

.slider ul.sliderpager li {
  padding: 0 3px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.caroufredsel/6.2.1/jquery.carouFredSel.packed.js"></script>

<!-- slider -->
<div class="slider" id="slider">
  <ul class="slider-carousel" id="slider-carousel">
    <li class="img1">
      <h3></h3>
      <p></p>
    </li>
    <li class="img2">
      <h3></h3>
      <p></p>
    </li>
    <li class="img3">
      <h3></h3>
      <p></p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sliderpager">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buscando por la documentación de la librería de `Caroufredsel`, encontré un ejemplo que te podría servir y que evita los espacios en blanco, seguí los pasos del ejemplo y lo traté de adaptar a tu especificación , espero te sirva

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict"

  $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
    responsive: true,
    items: {
      visible: 1,
      width: 900,
      height: 500
    },
    scroll: {
      duration: 250,
      timeoutDuration: 2500,
      fx: 'uncover-fade'
    },
    pagination: '#pager'
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 600px;
}

body * {
  font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 22px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: -250px 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

#carousel div {
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
}

#carousel img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

#title h3 {
  text-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 -3px 3px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.3), 3px 0 3px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.3), -3px 0 3px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

#title a {
  color: #fff;
}

#title a:hover {
  background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

#pager {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin: 235px 0 0 -60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

#pager a.selected span {
  background: #666;
}

#pager a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

#pager span {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-indent: -100px;
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.caroufredsel/6.2.1/jquery.carouFredSel.packed.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="carousel">
    <div><img src="https://placehold.it/500x300/ff0000" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://placehold.it/500x300/00ff00" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://placehold.it/500x300/0000ff" /></div>
  </div>
  <div id="pager"></div>
</div>
```

EL código anterior hace los slider pero con div no con list , pero puede ser una idea interesante y solucionaría tu problema.

> Si quieres mas ejemplo mita este
>   [LINK](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/72/)

Comment: aah float: left jaja no se me ocurrio, mil gracias!!!